# Checking if tmux session is still busy from outside the session itself

Tags: linux, tmux, session

How can I check if a tmux session is still busy (is running some process) from outside the session itself?

Comment: `tmux` is (almost) always running a process, even if it's just `bash`. Can you [be more precise](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/611825/edit) what you actually want, please.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `ps -x --forest` to determine whether the shells  in your tmux session have running child processes. If you want to do this programmatically, you should probably grab the pid of your tmux, then list its child shells using `ps --ppid <the tmux pid>`, and finally list their child processes using the same command. Quick and dirty :

```
ps --ppid $(ps -h -opid:1 --ppid $(ps x | awk ' $5 == "tmux" {print $1}') | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//')
```

However, if you know the pid of the subprocess you ran,you can just check whether it's still running.

Comment: Thank you very much. This however, did not allow me to track the tmux session by the tmux's ID. Still not solved....

Comment: You should therefore probably be more specific about your problem and why this does not solve it, because it seems I did not understand it.

Comment: A PID should *never* be used to do anything. A PID is random and the kernel can give the exact same PID to a different process after the original process has died. Clearly not for anything more than playing around. Google for more reasons.